# How to insert the current url link to form value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, onload

how to put the current url to form value. Here I am using two forms both form are same in coding like id class etc. I want to load the url to both forms.

Currently I am using windows.onload function, it's work only for first form not for second form. I want to load the url to both form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
window.onload=function()
{
document.getElementById('emd_ticket_page_link').value = window.location.href;
}

</script>
```

And My forms are

```
<div id="idsampleavailable" class="panel panel-default">

    <form name="submit_tickets" id="submit_tickets" action="" method="post" class="submit_tickets form-container wpas-form wpas-form-stacked"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div id="row3a" class="row ">
                <!-- text input-->
                <div class="col-md-12 woptdiv">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="label_emd_ticket_page_link" class="control-label" for="emd_ticket_page_link">
                            Product Link<span style="display: inline-flex;right: 0px; position: relative; top:-6px;">
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="emd_ticket_page_link" id="emd_ticket_page_link" value="" class="text input-md form-control"
                            placeholder="Page Link"></div>
                </div>
               </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="wpas-form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" name="singlebutton_submit_tickets" id="singlebutton_submit_tickets"
                        value="submit" class="submit wpas-button wpas-juibutton-success wpas-button-large btn-block col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">Submit
                        Ticket </button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


<div id="idnonsampleavailable" class="panel panel-default">

    <form name="submit_tickets" id="submit_tickets" action="" method="post" class="submit_tickets form-container wpas-form wpas-form-stacked"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div id="row3a" class="row ">
                <!-- text input-->
                <div class="col-md-12 woptdiv">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="label_emd_ticket_page_link" class="control-label" for="emd_ticket_page_link">
                            Product Link<span style="display: inline-flex;right: 0px; position: relative; top:-6px;">
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="emd_ticket_page_link" id="emd_ticket_page_link" value="" class="text input-md form-control"
                            placeholder="Page Link"></div>
                </div>
               </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="wpas-form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" name="singlebutton_submit_tickets" id="singlebutton_submit_tickets"
                        value="submit" class="submit wpas-button wpas-juibutton-success wpas-button-large btn-block col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">Submit
                        Ticket </button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML requires id's to be unique.

Change the second instance of the `'emd_ticket_page_link'` id to something unique and call `document.getElementById(new_id).value = window.location.href;` on it

Comment: Hi, I know different ID will work 100%. But I am using two forms in a single page. Each form has a different title only but remaining are the same. So I can't change the ID.

Answer (score 0):

window.load is not possible for this problem. So I finally used this code.

```
$pageurlform = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 
                "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```